# A question on the use of 'since'.

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conjunctions, writing-style

'Since' means throughout the period from a specified point in past time to the present. Can I use it to mean 'throughout the period from a specified point in past time to a specific **point also in the past**'

Example:

> And even after ten seasons **since that one in which** he learned how
>   to hunt, he was still unable to catch any deer.

I know the sentence could be phrased more smoothly, but I want it to sound that way. And so, *grammatically speaking*: Is 'since' used correctly here? Again grammatically? Does it mean (as I want it to mean):

> And even after ten seasons **from the time he** learned how to hunt,
>   he was still unable to catch any deer.

?

Many, many thanks.

Comment: Asking the same question on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52834/an-advanced-question-on-the-use-of-since) and [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233755/a-question-on-the-use-of-since) is frowned upon...

Comment: I did NOT know that. I am sorry. I just needed a swift answer. Should I delete it?

Comment: Decide on one site, delete the question on the other one.

Comment: The part of the question you focus on is not the one that matters. The operative time expression is "he was still unable to catch any deer," and it refers to a specific point in time which is, presumably, under discussion.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question, but thank you for your comment.

Comment: And even ten seasons after learning to hunt he was still unable to catch any deer.